# Prove that there are $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ for which $a_{1}a_{2}...a_{n}(\frac{1}{a_{1}} +\frac{1}{a_{2}}+...+\frac{1}{a_{n}})$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that for any $n\geq3$ there are distinct nonzero natural numbers $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ for which $a_{1}a_{2}...a_{n}(\frac{1}{a_{1}} +\frac{1}{a_{2}}+...+\frac{1}{a_{n}})$ is a perfect square.

My work so far: I've thought about the case of equality for Cauchy-Schwartz inequality ($a_{1}a_{2}...a_{n}(\frac{1}{a_{1}} +\frac{1}{a_{2}}+...+\frac{1}{a_{n}})\geq{n}^2$): $a_{1}^2=a_{2}^2=...=a_{n}^2$, but they are distinct numbers.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: possibly related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_divisor_number

Comment: Hello. It is better for you to add some more effort, or add the source of your question so that more people are motivated to take a look at it. In addition you can add more tags to the post! Otherwise, your post could be closed by moderators as well as getting downvotes. Good luck!

Comment: For the application of CS, are you thinking of $ ( \sum a_i ) ( \sum 1/a_i)  \geq n^2$? Note that the first term is not $ \prod a_i$. In any case, the inequality claim is still true, and in fact $ \geq n!$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

An important feature of such problems is scalability. In this problem, assume you are given a set of distinct numbers $b_1,\cdots,b_n$. Now, define $a_i=kb_i$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$ and try to adjust $k$ such that $a_{1}a_{2}...a_{n}(\frac{1}{a_{1}} +\frac{1}{a_{2}}+...+\frac{1}{a_{n}})=k^{n-1}b_{1}b_{2}...b_{n}(\frac{1}{b_{1}} +\frac{1}{b_{2}}+...+\frac{1}{b_{n}})$ is a perfect square.

**Update**

Some folks suggested that this approach will not work for odd values of $n$. I hope the even $n$ case is clear enough and everyone can go through it. The solution for odd $n$ is as follows.

Fix an integer $r\ge 2$ and let $a_1=r(r+1)$ and $a_2=r+1$. Then
$$
a_1\cdots a_n\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)=
r(r+1)^2a_3\cdots a_n\left(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{a_3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right),
$$for which, a sufficient condition for fulfilling the OP's request is that
$$
a_1\cdots a_n\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)=
ra_3\cdots a_n\left(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{a_3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)
$$ be a perfect square. Since we are dealing with an even number of components, the case of odd $n$ reduces to the case of even $n$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: If n is an odd number then $k^{n-1}$ is a perfect square and it's a dead end.

Comment: Not quite. The trick I used here was that I assumed two numbers among $b_1,\cdots ,b_n$, say $b_1$ and $b_2$, to have the following form: $b_1=r(r+1)c$ and $b_2=(r+1)c$ for some positive integers $r$ and $c$.

Comment: This answer really could/should be elaborated on a bit more please.

Comment: Dear @mike, I personally prefer to answer some questions in form of hints. This allows for an open ending and room for creativity of the solver. Any more elaborations will merely spoil the answer. Please carefully go through the details and feel free to ask questions.

Comment: excellent answer! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strategy to find such numbers.

Let's assume $a_1=1, a_2=2,a_3=3,  ..., a_n=n, a_{n+1}=x, a_{n+2}=kx$. We are going to find a pair $(x,k)$ such that the sequence $a_1, ..., a_{n+2}$ satisfies the condition of the problem.

It is very easy to see that our goal, now,  is to make
$$x(n!+kx(\frac{n!}{1}+\frac{n!}{2}+ ... +\frac{n!}{n})+k(n!))$$

a perfect square. To do so, we may suppose:

$$n!+kx(\frac{n!}{1}+\frac{n!}{2}+ ... +\frac{n!}{n})+k(n!)=m^2x,$$

where $m$ is a positive integer. Therefore our goal, now, is to find a triple $(x,k,m)$ such that the equality above holds.

We have:

$$n!+kx(\frac{n!}{1}+\frac{n!}{2}+ ... +\frac{n!}{n})+k(n!)=m^2x \\ \iff x(m^2-k(\frac{n!}{1}+\frac{n!}{2}+ ... +\frac{n!}{n}))=n!+k(n!). $$

An example of such $(x,k,m)$, is:

$$m+1=\frac{n!}{1}+\frac{n!}{2}+ ... +\frac{n!}{n}\\
k=m-1 \\ x=n!+k(n!).$$

We are done.

---

**Note:** There was no obligation to assume $a_1=1, a_2=2,a_3=3,  ..., a_n=n$ as initial values. We just chose these simple values to have an explicit example.

For example, if $n+2=4$, put $a_1=2, a_2=3$, then by following the same argument as above, we have $k=3$ and $x=24$. So $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(2,3,24,72);$

and, if $n+2=5$, we can easily obtain $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)=(1,2,3,60,540).$